# 'set' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, django

I have a dictionary name typecontext and I have a list named types. I want to take  five elements of types and add it to the dict typecontext. I am getting a error that set attribute has no object getitem.

```
 try:
    k=0
    typecontext = dict()
    for i in range(0, len(types), 5):
        print(i)
        if i + 5 < len(types):
            typecontext.update({'item_'+str(k) :types[i:i + 5]})
        else:
            typecontext.update({'item_' + str(k): types[i:len(types)]})
        k=k+1
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Whats the contents of types

Comment: its a set. It contains strings eg: types = set([u'abc', u'def', u'ghi']). and its length is 22

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your variable `types` is a `set` object. So when you try to slice it you get your error.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) function. It works with any iterable.